Irreducible actions of groups
Let $p$ be a prime and let $A$ be a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over the field of order $p$. Does $Aut(A)$ contains a group of the form $R\ltimes S$, where $R$ and $S$ are cyclic, $(|R|,|S|)=1=(|RS|,p)$ and the action of $RS$ on $A$ is irreducible and still every element of $A$ is centralized by some non-trivial element of $RS$? Assume also that the commutator subgroup of $RS$ is precisely $S$.
I think every element of $A$ should be centralized in this case actually by an element of $R$ or one of its conjugates. I was playing with GAP and I didn't find any such example, and unfortuntately I cannot even prove this, so I'm really curious if such an example exists or not. Do you have any idea on the matter?

If you take just $A=\mathbb F_2$ or $A=\mathbb F_3$ does it not fail already ? As every proper subgroup of $RS=Aut(A)$ is trivial, the action is irreducible. $A$ is centralized by the identity, the commutator is the trivial subgroup, say $S$ - with $R=S$ or $R=Sym_2$. Im surely missing some condition but i dont see what you seek. Any rationale to guide us ? Sorry in advance.  :)

@plm I meant centralized by "non-trivial" elements.
